# Some WordPress Menus are empty after edit

Tags: wordpress

I moved a WordPress 4.2.2 site from one server to another.
Now, after saving a menu (`/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=149`), it's cleared and empty. 
This happens to all menus created on the old server (for new created menus this doesn't happen).

The old menus do not have many pages (8-20 per menu), so this is not the 3.9.1 WP Bug with `max_input_vars`.

I tried to add a page before saving or sort them, but the items are always gone after saving

**Edit:** The Menu still exists after saving, but it's empty

Comment: This might be happening because of one of your plugins or menu plugins(if you have one). Try disactivating your plugins and see if your error persist. I advice you to do so usually one by one so you can locate your problem

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I deactivated all plugins and switched the theme to Twenty Fifteen - it's still the same. The old menus are empty after saving.

Comment: I was wrong about the deletion of the menu, it still exist. The select-menu-switch changes to the first, but it's still in the list. (changed the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the database and found out that there was an error in the `term_taxonomy` table.

In my WordPress there are menus and categories with the same name, but for the broken menus there are two entries (same `term_id`) in the `term_taxonomy` table. One with `nav_menu` as `taxonomy` (the correct one) but another with `category` as `taxonomy`.

The `category` break my menu because it should link to an other id.

I have no idea how this could happen, but for me this solved the problem:

- This SQL lists all my broken menus: `SELECT count(*) as anzahl, term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy group by term_id having anzahl > 1` (the problem exists when one `term_id` is linked more than one time with an id)
- Edit the Category-Entry with the `term_id`: http://domain.de/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&post_type=post&tag_ID=**THE-ID**
- Save the Entry

Now the wrong entry is gone an the category is created with an other id.